# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_set_charset' (T_STRING) in /home/csgoxdne/public_html/set.php on line 4

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_set_charset' (T_STRING) in /home/csgoxdne/public_html/set.php on line 4

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost:3306", "csgoxdnet", "secretpassword");
  if ($mysqli->error) print ("Error connecting! Message: ".$mysqli->error) 
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');

function fetchinfo($rowname,$tablename,$finder,$findervalue)
  {($finder == "1");
      $query ="SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE rowname = '$rowname'";
      $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query); 
}
else
    {
         $query = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE `$finder`='$findervalue'"
         if (!$query)   {die    ('Invalid query: '.$mysqli->error)}
         $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
 }
 return $result;
```

I honestly can't fix the error. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Looks like a missing semicolon on line 3.

Answer (score -3):

use this way

```
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```